# OpenCV line detection and extraction using ios

Tags: ios, opencv

Hi i am using **opencv** for the line detection in ios. This is for my final year project. I want to  upload the image of ecg and then extract the line from this for that i have used the opencv and sucessfuly i have extracted the line but now i want to save the line and facing much problem in that can anyone help me or any tutorial ?

Comment: What do you mean by "saving" the lines ?

Comment: I think [this](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/file_input_output_with_xml_yml/file_input_output_with_xml_yml.html) should help you. It says how to read and write to files. You can store your lines in however format you want.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something quickly, I think it can help you:

```
void write_lines_to_file ( string file_name, vector<vector<Point> > lines )
{
  FileStorage fs ( file_name, FileStorage::WRITE );
  fs << "lines" << "[";
  for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
    {
      // I've assumed each line is a vector< Point >, in index [0] the head and index [1] the tail.
      fs << "{:" << "x1" << lines[i].at ( 0 ).x << "y1" << lines[i].at ( 0 ).y << "x2" << lines[i].at ( 1 ).x << "y2" << lines[i].at ( 1 ).y << "}";
    }
  fs.release();
}
```

I didn't test it and I made my own assumptions, so please be cautious when you want to use it.